# Can we find the endorser details in smart contract during execution(Hyperledger Fabric)?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Can we find the endorser details in smart contract during execution(Hyperledger Fabric) ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on which details are you looking after? Usually, the chaincode is bonded to one specific endorser, whiche doesn't change over time.

Comment: I want to extract the endorser id or endpoint in the chaincode function.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the below link, by using this library you access  MSPid, fabric-ca certificate details inside the chaincode

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/blob/main/pkg/cid/README.md

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/endorsement-policies.html

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/main/asset-transfer-secured-agreement/chaincode-go/asset_transfer.go

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the link. But my question was not about client identity, it was about endorser information.

Comment: check this one here they mentioned one function in Golang which is used to set Organisation into endorsement.  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/endorsement-policies.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use the internal docker build mechanism then the only thing available to chaincode is `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID`

I've not tried but if you use an external builder you could add more information yourself during the run part see https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/cc_launcher.html?highlight=builder#external-builder-and-launcher-api

and if you use chaincode as a service then it may be possible for you to bake something into the image you use in different orgs